# Using Rspec to send post on create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to use Rspec to send a post on my create action, I have simple controller logic. This is an api app, i run my rspec and it returns with a 422 status. I am trying to figure out whether or not my spec is sending information to the controller. These are the controller/specs in question, how do i insert information into the create method. So far all tutorials seem to be using the same syntax as mine. Thanks in advance

**Ignore the hardcoded user_id in my factory, still learning factories and fixing dependency ones**

```
#post_controller    
def create
  if User.exists?(params[:user_id])
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save 
    render json: @post, status: 200
  else
    render status: 422
  end
end   

#spec
it "saves a new post in the database" do
  attrs = attributes_for(:post)
  post :create, post: attrs
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
end

#factory
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :post do
   title "This is a new title"
   body "This is the body"
   user_id 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is your `user_id` in `params[:post][:user_id]`?

Comment: it is included in my post params

Comment: Yes but you don't reach post_params, cause this check is false if User.exists?(params[:user_id])

Comment: the end point takes the user_id as well, when testing the endpoint manually it works fine.